# Creating articles in front end. Status field is disabled and articles remain unpublished

Tags: joomla-3.x, articles, front-end, user-groups, permissions

I have a site were certain users can create, edit and publish articles on the front end. These users are using the default "Author", "Editor", "Publisher" user groups and permissions.

They can do all tasks fine except when first creating an article it is always unpublished. In the form the status field is html disabled so you can't edit it, however it is set to "Published". Regardless of what this field says when you save the first time the article is always unpublished.

You can then edit it and publish it without problems, however we want to be able to create and publish the first time.

I have found this isn't a problem for Managers/super users despite having the same article permissions set. Have tried increasing permissions for articles and log in/out numerous times but the only way I have found to fix this is give a user the Manager role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Joomla ACL

#### 1. Edit State Privilege

In order for a user to be able to set/switch the publishing status of a content item (published/unpublished etc), they need to have the **Edit State** permission assigned on them.

#### 2. Core Usergroups

From the core front-end usergroups, only the **Publisher** has this kind of permission. So only users of that usergroup can set / edit this setting for an article. All the other usergroups will be able to create an article and this will default to unpublished, until another user with higher privileges take care of it.

### Create Article Form

Now, what you are describing with the front-end article form, isn't the default behavior. The **Status field** should be hidden for when a user don't have the privilege to edit it and visible and normally working in the other case.

So, first please confirm you are using the **latest Joomla version**.
Then I would look into the **template overrides** for the **`com_content`**, as it is possible that your template has its own article form, that overrides the default one.

> #### Update
>
> Well, here is a quick tip for you to make a test test You can assign on your Create Article menu item, the core Protostar
>   template and see how it works for the article submission.

### Extend Frontend Articles Management

Moreover, if you would like more front-end control for articles management, there are some extensions that allow this:

- [**Article Factory Manager**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/article-factory-manager)
- [**User Article Manager**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/user-article-manager)

#### Build your own

If you feel you want to take it to the next level, then you can integrate a custom front-end application with [**Fabrik**](http://fabrikar.com) or another similar tool, building your own lists and forms for managing your articles.

Answer (score 1):

You can give to an author the power to publish immediatly an article :
ARTICLE > PArameters > Right 
 for Author : turn "Change the status" to allowed (no Disallowed)
               Then when an author create an article with the frontend, his status is immediately "allowed"